# Building an Automated 5-day week, 73 week Calendar

Tags: calendar

I am working on building an online calendar that will, for the moment, simply display what the current date is according to the calendar my circle of friends are creating from scratch, with only some attention paid to the Gregorian Calendar. The code, what I have so far, which is calculating which day of the 5-day week it is, and how the rest of the calendar will be calculated are below. I don't know if what I have coded so far is efficient, or even correct, much less how to continue about figuring out the weeks and months, considering.

```
<?php

echo "<p><p><p> According to the Gregorian Calender, ";
echo "today is " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";

$d1=strtotime("October 18, 2015");
$d2=ceil(($d1-time())/60/60/24);

echo "<p>There are " . $d2 ." days since First Founding, First Sol.<p>";

if ($d2 < "365") { $lastdigit = $d2%10; }

echo "$lastdigit <br>";

if ($lastdigit == "-1") { echo "Today is Mercury."; }
if ($lastdigit == "-2") { echo "Today is Venus."; }
if ($lastdigit == "-3") { echo "Today is Terra."; }
if ($lastdigit == "-4") { echo "Today is Mars."; }
if ($lastdigit == "-5") { echo "Today is Sol."; }
if ($lastdigit == "-6") { echo "Today is Mercury."; }
if ($lastdigit == "-7") { echo "Today is Venus."; }
if ($lastdigit == "-8") { echo "Today is Terra."; }
if ($lastdigit == "-9") { echo "Today is Mars."; }
if ($lastdigit == "0") { echo "Today is Sol."; }
if ($lastdigit == "1") { echo "Today is Mercury."; }
if ($lastdigit == "2") { echo "Today is Venus."; }
if ($lastdigit == "3") { echo "Today is Terra."; }
if ($lastdigit == "4") { echo "Today is Mars."; }
if ($lastdigit == "5") { echo "Today is Sol."; }
if ($lastdigit == "6") { echo "Today is Mercury."; }
if ($lastdigit == "7") { echo "Today is Venus."; }
if ($lastdigit == "8") { echo "Today is Terra."; }
if ($lastdigit == "9") { echo "Today is Mars."; }

$year = date('Y');
$truyear = $year-1;

function is_leapyear_working($truyear) {
    if((($truyear%4==0) && ($truyear%100!=0)) || $truyear%400==0) {
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if(($d2 == "365") && ($is_leapyear_working == "true")) { echo "Today is Luna."; }
if(($d2 == "365") && ($is_leapyear_working == "false")) { echo "Today is Mars."; }

if ($d2 == "-29") {
    echo "<p>First Apprentice, Third Mars<p>";
}

echo "*Year* (st/nd/rd/th) *Month*, *Week* (st/nd/rd) *Day*";

echo "<p> October 18, 2015 according the Gregorian Calender is the First Founding, First Sol. This is, essentially, the \"New Years Day\" of the Ecclesia Chaotica. One week within the Ecclesic Calender is Five  days in length, named in order, Sol, Mercury, Venus, Terra, and Mars. There are three weeks in every month, with twenty-four months in a year, called, in order, The Founding, The Apprentice, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24. Seventy-three weeks exist in a year, with one of said weeks existing \"outside of time.\" This week is known as the Week of Fotamacus, in honour of him, the God of Chaotic Time. On a Leap Year, every four years,* which are the Second, Sixth, Tenth, Fourteenth, etc. The Week of Fotamacus contains an extra day, dubbed Luna, which falls between Terra and Mars on that Week.<p> *The additional day every Leap Year is due to one cycle around the Sun taking 365.248 days, not a perfect 365, dates must be adjusted to account for this change.";

?>
```

Comment: Does this code give the expected output for a range of test inputs? What are you actually asking?

Comment: It shows the accurate day of the week for most dates I plug into it. I need help figuring out how to figure out what year, month and week of the month it will be.